# How to access post data from Ajax in Controller?

Tags: ajax, cakephp-2.0

I am showing some data with Soap web service in a table.Each row has check box.Now i want to pass the checked check box result(Complete row) to the Controller file.Table data is in Index function and i want to post it to the view function.I tried this code.

Php Code

```
 <?php  echo $this->Form->checkbox('reorder',array('id' => 'reorder' ,'class' => 'checkbox', 
 'value' => $datarow->cihs_item, 'data-desc' => $datarow->cihs_description ?>
```

Ajax Code

```
$(".checkbox").click(function(){        
if ( $(this).is(":checked") ) {
        $.post( "services/view", {itemid: $(this).val(), itemvalue: $(this).attr("data-desc")
```

My question is this data is not coming from any table(No Model). So can i access it with $this->request->data[itemvalue] in view function?

Thanks

Comment: Try it and see for yourself. But the aswer is: Yes, not any different from any other POST in an action.

Comment: In console window i got the correct result.How i set this request data array in controller and echo it in view.i tried this one.

Comment: if($this->request->is('post')) { $name = $this->request->data['itemvalue'];
   $this->set(compact('name'));
  }